# iOS/iPhone SDK: initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder not being called

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I'm trying to save an `NSMutableArray` called queueArray so it can be loaded again after the app has been quit.  I used a few tutorials to get me going and this is the code I have come up with.  The problem seems to be that "`initWithCoder`" and "`encodeWithCoder`" are not being called, shown by no `NSLog` calls and no stopping at breakpoints.  I have added the `NSCoding` protocol to the .h file and I know that queueArray is not nil and it contains `MPMediaItem`s.  Here is some of the code I use to try to save and load the array:

```
-(IBAction)saveQueuePressed {

     NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *filePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"queueArray.archive"];

     //should cause encodeWithCoder to be called
     [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:queueArray toFile:filePath];

}

-(IBAction)loadQueuePressed {

     NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *filePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"queueArray.archive"];

     //should cause initWithCoder to be called
     queueArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];

}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

     NSLog(@"encodeWithCoder");

     [coder encodeObject:queueArray forKey:@"savedQueueArray"];
}



-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

     NSLog(@"initWithCoder");

     queueArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"savedQueueArray"];

     return self;

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the "101010" button to format code.

Answer (score 1):

The `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder` methods are called when you archive/unarchive an object that responds to them. From what I understand, you have those methods in your class, but the object you are actually archiving (`queueArray`) is not an instance of that class, it's an `NSMutableArray`.

If you do want to save your entire object, you can change your saveQueue method to this

```
-(IBAction)saveQueuePressed {

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"queueArray.archive"];

    // saving the array shouldn't, but saving the self object
    //should cause encodeWithCoder to be called:
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:filePath];
}
```

But if you just want to save the array, I guess you can just use `saveQueuePressed` and `loadQueuePressed`, I don't think you need the `encode/init WithCoder:` methods

Update:
Maybe your path is not right.
Try

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [[rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"queueArray.archive"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
```

Comment: I have changed the code to:  //to save
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/queueArrayFile", rootPath];
 
[queueArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
 
//to retrieve
NSMutableArray *retrievedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 

However, it is still not working as the array is empty when I retrieve it.  I dont think I am able to save an MSMutableArray full of MPMediaItems.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Filipe is right! Your comment said you still didn't use his method.

I had this issue too. Switching from the dictionary's atomic write method to the keyedArchiver fixed it, luckily I only had to change one thing, the line that said writeToFile: is now the archive function.

Now my program's working. For some reason, even when responding to NSCoding, the custom object is not being encoded and breaks my dictionary. Is this a bug with iOS? I've read a fair number of Apple Manuals, but I've also seen a fair number of typos and missing info (For example, try MKMapRect functions without the videos to explain them), or Core Animations referencing the Run Loop before you learn threading, I could go on, half finished sentences in Quartz... so yeah, I've read the manuals and this perplexes me, we have to get a more open iOS SDK at some point, hopefully